# django: is it possible to change widget of a form field according to content in another form field?

Tags: html, django

Sorry for this poorly-worded title. What I really would like to know is for a form like the following:

```
<form id="searchform" action="/calbase" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <select name="search_type">
                    <option value="asset_number">Asset #</option>
                    <option value="calibrated_by">Calibrated by</option>
                    <option value="department">Department</option>
                    <option value="description">Description</option>
                    <option value="expiring_soon">Expiring soon</option>
                    <option value="flagged">Flagged</option>
                    <option value="manufacturer">Manufacturer</option>
                    <option value="model">Model</option>
                    <option value="serial #">Serial #</option>
                    <option value="test">Test</option>
                </select>
                <input class="searchfield" id="searchbox" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="searchbutton" type="submit">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>

              </form>
```

I have a select widget for search_type and searchfield for search_content(q). For some of the search_type, like department and test, I would like search_content be using drop down select widget and the user can just choose which department(from a list) to search by. And for expiring soon, the search_content should be uneditable.

Is there a easy way of achieving this?

Comment: You want your search_type list change when you use different keyword to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sure if I understood you correctly, but I think that would be best done using JavaScript.

If your "department lists" aren't very long, just render all the `selects` the user could see, and hide them visually (using `display: none` on their DOM `id`s).

When the user picks the appropriate field in the `search_type` list, reveal the related `select` element and hide the `input[type="text"]` element.